# Issues with SOAP API login callout

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest, apexrest

I have the following piece of code that used to work before:

```
Custom_Data__c cData = [SELECT Password__c, Security_Token__c, Username__c FROM Custom_Data__c WHERE Name = :Constants.CURRENCY_TYPE_BATCH_CUSTOM_DATA_NAME];
String user = cData.Username__c;
String pass = cData.Password__c + (cData.Security_Token__c == null ? '' : cData.Security_Token__c);
String sessionId = login(user, pass);


private static String login(String user, String password) {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('POST');   
    req.setTimeout(60000);
    req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/Soap/u/51.0');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');        
    req.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
    req.setBody('<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Header/><Body><login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><username>' + user + '</username><password>' + password + '</password></login></Body></Envelope>');        
    HttpResponse res =  new Http().send(req);
    system.debug(res);
    if(res.getStatusCode() == 200){
        Dom.Document responseDocument = res.getBodyDocument();
        Dom.Xmlnode rootElm = responseDocument.getRootElement(); // soapenv:Envelope
        Dom.Xmlnode bodyElm = rootElm.getChildElement('Body', Constants.NS_SOAP); // soapenv:Body 
        Dom.Xmlnode loginResponseElm = bodyElm.getChildElement('loginResponse', Constants.NS_SF); // loginResponse
        Dom.Xmlnode resultElm = loginResponseElm.getChildElement('result', Constants.NS_SF); // result
        Dom.Xmlnode sessionIdElm = resultElm.getChildElement('sessionId', Constants.NS_SF); // sessionId
        return sessionIdElm.getText();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am getting the following error :

```
System.HttpResponse[Status=Server Error, StatusCode=500]
```

Also when I look at the response body I get the following details:

```
INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.
```

I made sure that the login credentials are up to date and got a new security token.
Also I am able to login with that user on the main login page.
When inspecting the login history for the user I see the following
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the fact that I was retrieving the password from an encrypted field. I managed to solve it by creating a permission set that with the View Encrypted data access and assigned it to the user that was running the code.